# Reduce control-c latency in xterm and tmux

Tags: tmux, xterm

When using `tmux` under `xterm`, I am unable to quickly stop process that is overwhelming the terminal with output. The interrupt eventually arrives but only after a long delay. This problem does not appear when not using `tmux` or when using a different X11 terminal (oddly, regardless of tmux being used).

What could be the cause of such symptoms and how can I reduce this latency? My `TERM` is `screen-256color` under `tmux`.

Comment: If you start xterm with the `-j` or `-s` options (or both), does that help?

Comment: The issue persists with `-j`  and `-s` options as well as both.

Answer (score 2):

Quite possibly there's too much data scrolling through your xterm when you're trying to stop it. The moment you hit "CTRL+C", the process is being stopped, but the output which was buffered will still flow to your console.

The latency is your X (in this case xterm) displaying the information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with `tmux` but with the interaction between `tmux` and `xterm`.

The issue is discussed in the GitHub issue [Backoff mechanism in xterm #684](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/684).

The conclusion, as seen from the `tmux` POV at least, is that

> [...] `xterm` is slower than `rxvt` so there is more opportunity for `tmux` to buffer and it takes longer to drain.